# How to Remove Spacing between two formview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using two `FormViews` to insert, and update data. I would like to remove the space between these two `FormViews`. How can I do that? 
Can I use a CSS class to remove that space? 
Please help.

Thanks & regards, Mayur.

Here is the Html code:

```
       <table class="fv">
    <tr>
    <td  colspan="2" class="style12"><b>Select Subscriber</b></td><td class="td" colspan="2" align="right"> * Required Field</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="style5"></td><td class="style14"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="fv" width="100%" >
    <tr>
        <td class="style15">
            <b>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="District:"></asp:Label></b>
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldistrict" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4"
                DataTextField="district_name" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddldistrict_SelectedIndexChanged"
                DataValueField="district_id" Width="150px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EBPConnectionString1 %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [district_name], [district_id] FROM [districts_mst] WHERE (([lang_id] = @lang_id) AND ([state_id] = @state_id))">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="2" Name="lang_id" Type="Int64" />
                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="35" Name="state_id" Type="Int64" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td class="style2">
            <b>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSubId" runat="server" Text="Subscriber Id:"></asp:Label></b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSub" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"
                DataTextField="SubId" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSub_SelectedIndexChanged" DataValueField="SubId"
                Width="150px" OnDataBound="MyListDataBound">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EBPConnectionString1 %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [SubId], [Ser] FROM [Subsciber] WHERE ([District] = @District)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddldistrict" Name="District" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                        Type="Int64" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="999px" style="margin-right: 0px">
    <tr>
    <td  class="style12"><b>Subscriber Information</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="style13"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <asp:FormView ID="FV" runat="server" Width="999px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
        CssClass="fv">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSubId" runat="server" Text="Subscriber Id:"></asp:Label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="SubIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SubId") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFName" runat="server" Text="Name:"></asp:Label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAdd" runat="server" Text="Address:"></asp:Label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text="State:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="state_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("state_name") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDist" runat="server" Text="District:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="district_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("district_name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbltaluka" runat="server" Text="Taluka:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="taluka_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("taluka_name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Pincode:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="pincodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pincode") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Telephone No:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="TelNoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TelNo") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSubId" runat="server" Text="Subscriber Id:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="SubIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SubId") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFName" runat="server" Text="Name:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAdd" runat="server" Text="Address:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text="State:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="state_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("state_name") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDist" runat="server" Text="District:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="district_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("district_name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbltaluka" runat="server" Text="Taluka:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="taluka_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("taluka_name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Pincode:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="pincodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pincode") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Telephone No:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TelNoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TelNo") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSubId" runat="server" Text="Id:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style16">
                        <asp:Label ID="SubIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SubId") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFName" runat="server" Text="Name:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style17">
                        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAdd" runat="server" Text="Address:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AddressLabel" runat="server" Width="200px" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text="State:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="state_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("state_name") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDist" runat="server" Text="District:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style16">
                        <asp:Label ID="district_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("district_name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbltaluka" runat="server" Text="Taluka:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style17">
                        <asp:Label ID="taluka_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("taluka_name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Pincode:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="pincodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pincode") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Telephone No:"></asp:Label>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="TelNoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TelNo") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <%--  <td>
                         <b> <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Magazine name:"></asp:Label> </b>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Magid") %>' />
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        <b> <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Subscription Period:"></asp:Label> </b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Period") %>'/> <asp:Label runat="server" text="years"></asp:Label>
                    </td>--%>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>

 <table width="999px">
    <tr>
    <td  class="style12"><b>Magazine Information</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="style13"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:FormView ID="FV1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="999px"
        DefaultMode="Edit" CssClass="fv">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Magazine Name:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMagazine" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MagId") %>'
                            DataTextField="name" DataValueField="magid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMagazine_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Price:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>' Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Period:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="PeriodLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Period") %>' Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Subscription Period:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubPeriod" runat="server" DataTextField="period" DataValueField="period"
                            AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSubPeriod_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Amount:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="amountLabel" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Name:
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMagazine" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MagId") %>'
                            DataTextField="name" DataValueField="magid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Price:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>' Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Period:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="PeriodLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Period") %>' Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Qty:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Qty") %>' OnTextChanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Amount:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="amountLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("amount") %>' Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Name:
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMagazine" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MagId") %>'
                            DataTextField="name" DataValueField="magid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Price:
                        <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Period:
                        <asp:Label ID="PeriodLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Period") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Qty:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Qty") %>' OnTextChanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Amount:
                        <asp:Label ID="amountLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("amount") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

Comment: You should show use the aspx-markup of the two formview and html code generated by ASP.NET(view source in browser).

Comment: The code you've posted is **not** the html-code but the serverside ASP.NET. Have you tried to remove the empty line between both FormViews? Aprt from that, there is a table between both FormViews! `<table width="999px">
    <tr>
    <td  class="style12"><b>Magazine Information</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="style13"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure you can use CSS to customize precisely how you want the forms to look like.

consider removing any margin, padding, top/bottom values, or simply reset them to zeroes

Comment: i hadn't use anything in this page. but still it shows some space in two formviews. is there any other way to remove that space.

Comment: ok, consider using any of the debugging tools like Firebug, Web Developer toolbar to see exactly what is applied to your forms, and to know what you should add/remove in order to make it match your needs.